# asyncio import issues - no attribute 'StreamReader'

Tags: python-3.x, windows, python-import, python-asyncio

I have had asyncio and websockets work fine several times, but for some reason it sometimes refuses to run and will refuse to ever run again. I have had this happen across multiple devices, with code as simple as just imports:

```
import asyncio
import json
import websockets
```

Interestingly, when using Pydroid3 on Android, any code I write with asyncio works fine, but only until I save it to a file. Once it's been saved, it stops working. I can copy all the text and paste it to a new, unsaved file and it again works fine until saved. This awful solution does not work for Windows, unfortunately. I am using Python 3.9.0 for Windows. The stacktrace produced by running the code shown above is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\AtomTests\socket.py", line 1, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 23, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\AtomTests\socket.py", line 3, in <module>
    import websockets
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\websockets\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .auth import *  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\websockets\auth.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .exceptions import InvalidHeader
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\websockets\exceptions.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .http import Headers, HeadersLike
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\websockets\http.py", line 70, in <module>
    async def read_request(stream: asyncio.StreamReader) -> Tuple[str, "Headers"]:
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'StreamReader' (most likely due to a circular import)
[Finished in 0.158s]
```

I've searched a bit for this error, but either it's uncommon or I'm just blind, because I couldn't find anything. Has anyone else had this happen to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your local `socket.py` file is shadowing Python’s `socket` module. Rename your file and your imports will work.